# gpg Timeout in WSL1 when signing

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg

I am new to GPG keys. I created two in WSL to sign my git commits.

However, I cannot use these keys because all sign commands would time out.

```bsh
gpg-agent
```

> gpg-agent[2416]: gpg-agent running and available

```bsh
echo "test" | gpg2 --clearsign
```

> -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
> Hash: SHA512
>
> test
> gpg: signing failed: Timeout
> gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Timeout

```bsh
gpg2 -K
```

Output:

```bsh
/home/ME/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-----------------------------
sec   rsa4096 2022-01-06 [SC] [expires: 2022-01-07]
      ...
uid           [ultimate] MY NAME <mail@myname.tld>
ssb   rsa4096 2022-01-06 [E] [expires: 2022-01-07]

sec   rsa4096 2022-01-06 [SC] [expires: 2023-01-06]
      ...
uid           [ultimate] MY NAME <my.name@employer.tld>
ssb   rsa4096 2022-01-06 [E] [expires: 2023-01-06]
```

Remove personal GPG key also times out:

```bsh
gpg --delete-secret-keys mail@myname.tld
```

> gpg: deleting secret key failed: Timeout
> gpg: deleting secret subkey failed: Timeout
> gpg: mail@myname.tld: delete key failed: Timeout

- I tried with `gpg` and `gpg2`
- I added `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to `~/.bashrc`
- I tried with `pinentry-tty`

Environment:

- WSL1
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Windows, the timeouts were gone.

I did a number of things and I cannot say if any of these thing caused the timeouts to disappear beyond mere restart:

- disable IPv6 in Windows

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry
> Choice 3 (tty)
```

```bsh
unset DISPLAY
```

```bsh
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

Add to `bashrc`

```bsh
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null
```

```bsh
sudo apt install gnupg2
sudo apt-get install -y pinentry-tty
```